# English words dictionary database for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7, dictionary

I want to integrate an English dictionary function into my Windows Phone 7 application. Is there such a file or database available somewhere that contains all valid English words?

By the way, I only need something containing the list of words in order to validate inputs made by users. Other things such as definitions, phonetics, thesauruses, etc... are not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this link](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/) (text file). It obviously doesn't have all valid words, but it should be reasonably effective.

The spell check API that's integrated isn't exposed to developers, so you'll have to make do with a text file like this.

Also, if you only need to check the validity of the word that the user enters in a text input of some kind, then all you need to do is set `InputScope="Text"` in the XAML declaration.

Hope this helps.